# Default value for Html5 input attributes like min , max ,size etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, w3c

what is or where can i get the default value for Html5 input attributes if the attribute is not set

Say for example

```
<input type="number"/>
```

what is the max and min value that is acceptable and what is the value of other attributes like size ,maxlength,width,height,pattern etc..

Comment: if the attribute is not set at all, you cant get its default value

Comment: Hi there, I think the default values like width and height is based on the browser default used in viewing your page. Different browsers use different dimensions and you can see those by inspecting element. For max-length and other values, the you may have to specify in your Css.

Comment: There is a difference between HTML attributes and CSS style properties. For instance, the `width` attribute is used only with `<input type="image">`; it has no meaning for `number` type. But there is the CSS `width` which does have meaning for all `input` elements. Your question is quite broad: the answer is different for different items you mention.

Comment: what about min and max values

Answer (score 2):

> what is or where can i get the default value for Html5 input
>   attributes if the attribute is not set

Usually if the value is not set, it is empty. However, some of the attributes have default values like `type` (text), `disabled` (false), `readonly`  (false). Check [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for detailed info.

> what is the max and min value that is acceptable and what is the value
>   of other attributes like size ,maxlength,width,height,pattern etc..

I think [this W3C link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) has pretty good information about min and max value of the things you listed

> ⓘ min = floating-point number **NEW** The expected lower bound for the
>   element’s value.
>
> ⓘ max = floating-point number **NEW** The expected upper
>   bound for the element’s value.

Answer (score 0):

use "NODE.getAttribute()"

```
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');    
[].forEach.call(inputs,function(input){
   console.log(input.getAttribute('width')):
});

// replace width with value that you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 min max step has below default values

```
   min  Minimum value of the range. Default minimum value is 0.
   max  Maximum value of the range. Default maximum value is 100.
   step This is Step scale factor of the slider, default value is 1 and only allowing integer number unless minimum value is non integer number.
```

Please refer http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/04-minmaxstep.html